# JavaScript Absolute Positioning Not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am try position a div using absolute positioning and it works fine in Safari and Firefox but fails in IE and I can't figure out why. The code is this:

```
var tempX=123;
var tempY=456;
var commentnum=3;
var bodyelement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.setAttribute('id', 'comment_text'+commentnum);
newdiv.setAttribute('style', 'text-align:center;z-index:10001;left:'+(tempX-23)+'px;top:'+(tempY-80)+'px;position:absolute;');
newdiv.innerHTML = commenthtml;
bodyelement.appendChild(newdiv);
```

The script is suppose to generate a div where the user clicks the mouse. But in IE it places the div to the left side and then stacks them on top of each other. Can anyone give me an idea why this is not working?

Comment: What sort of output are you getting? I guess the div should appear but doesn't change position when the window is resized, right?

Comment: It places the div to the left side of the screen and stacks them on top of eacho ther

Comment: "Them"?  What do you mean, "them"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to quirksmode, `setAttribute` can not be used to set the `style` attribute in IE.

http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2005/03/setAttribute_does_not_work_in_IE_when_used_with_th.html

> Using setAttribute, you should be able to set any attribute on an element. It appears that in IE, trying to set the style attribute does not work.

Instead you may need to set the style properties individually:

```
newdiv.style.textAlign = 'center';
newdiv.style.zIndex = 10001;
newdiv.style.left = (tempX-23) + 'px';
newdiv.style.top = (tempY-80) + 'px';
newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
```

---

**EDIT:**

It appears as though `IE` has a `cssText` property. I'm not sure about browser support, but perhaps you could test for it.

```
if( 'cssText' in newdiv.style ) {
    newdiv.style.cssText = 'text-align:center;z-index:10001;left:'+(tempX-23)+'px;top:'+(tempY-80)+'px;position:absolute;';
} else {
    newdiv.setAttribute('style', 'text-align:center;z-index:10001;left:'+(tempX-23)+'px;top:'+(tempY-80)+'px;position:absolute;');
}
```

Tested `cssText` in Chrome 10 and Firefox 3.6, and it works.

---

**EDIT2:**

It appears as though [there's wide support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#t30) for that property on `elem.style`, so you may just want to use it instead of `setAttribute()`.

```
newdiv.style.cssText = 'text-align:center;z-index:10001;left:'+(tempX-23)+'px;top:'+(tempY-80)+'px;position:absolute;';
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved a problem I've been working on for 9 hours now!

Answer (score 3):

Try assigning the style directly, not via `setAttribute`:

```
newdiv.style.position = "absolute";
newdiv.style.left = (tempX-23) + "px";
newdiv.style.top = (tempY-80) + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Could your answer be as simple as `position:relative` assigned to `body` ?
The way your divs are acting seems like the second is being positioned differently due to the flow of the parent container relative to its children.